# Storing listObject data from AWS S3 SDK in Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, callback, scope

I am building a serverless application using AWS S3. In my web app, I have a table that lists the objects inside one of my S3 buckets. As my code is terribly spaghetti, I am trying to move the functions that build the table, get the S3 bucket object list, etc, into separate files and functions.
This is the code that gets the S3 list:

```
function listS3Objects() {
    s3.listObjects(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return alert(err.message);
        }
    });
}
```

My question is: how can I access "data" from outside the callback function, so I can pass it as argument to other functions (like the one actually building the table)?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). For the AWS SDK calls you can add `.promise()` after it to make it into a promise, which allows for `async/await` syntax.